# Comparing dictionaries based on a combination of keys

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have a list "records" like this

```
data = [
    {'id':1, 'name': 'A', 'price': 10, 'url': 'foo'},
    {'id':2, 'name': 'A', 'price': 20, 'url': 'bar'},
    {'id':3, 'name': 'A', 'price': 30, 'url': 'baz'},
    {'id':4, 'name': 'A', 'price': 10, 'url': 'baz'},
    {'id':5, 'name': 'A', 'price': 20, 'url': 'bar'},
    {'id':6, 'name': 'A', 'price': 30, 'url': 'foo'},
    {'id':7, 'name': 'A', 'price': 99, 'url': 'quu'},
    {'id':8, 'name': 'B', 'price': 10, 'url': 'foo'},
]
```

I want to remove records that are "duplicates", where equality is defined by a list of logical conditions. Each element in the list is an OR condition, and all elements are ANDed together. For example:

```
filters = [  ['name'],   ['price', 'url']  ]
```

means that two records are considered equal if their name AND (their price OR url) are equal. For the above example:

```
For item 1 the duplicates are 4 (by name and price) and 6 (name+url)
For item 2 - 5 (name+price, name+url)
For item 3 - 4 (name+url) and 6 (name+price)
For item 7 there are no duplicates (neither price nor url match)
For item 8 there are no duplicates (name doesn't match)
```

So the resulting list must contain items 1, 2, 3, 7 and 8.

Please take into account that

- there might be more AND conditions: `['name'], ['price', 'url'], ['weight'], ['size'], ...`
- the OR groups in the conditions list can be longer than 2 items, e.g. `['name'], ['price', 'url', 'weight']...`
- the source list is very long, an `O(n^2)` alogirthm is out of the question

Comment: If you have lots of them, you should seriously consider using something like `sqlite3` instead of a dictionary.

Comment: So where is the question? You have the data designed. You know what the functions should do. Where is the problem? This sounds a lot more like please write my code for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the idea of Tim Pietzcker, the following is working for me:

We start by converting the CNF condition like `a&(b|c)` into a DNF: `(a&b)|(a&c)`. Using the list notation as in the question, i.e `[ [a], [b, c] ]`, the DNF will be `[ [a, b], [a, c] ]`.  In python this is as simple as `itertools.product(*filters)`.

Then we iterate over the list and for each conjunct in the DNF create a composite key:

```
( (a, rec[a]), (b, rec[b]) )
```

and check if any of the keys have been seen already. If not, we consider the record to be unique and add its keys to the `seen` set:

The code:

```
seen = set()
dnf = list(itertools.product(*filters))

for item in data:
    keys = set(
        tuple((field, item.get(field, None)) for field in conjunct) 
        for conjunct in dnf)
    if keys.isdisjoint(seen):
        seen |= keys
        print item # unique
```

Kudos to Tim for giving me an idea. If anyone sees any problems with this solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 8):

The way to avoid doing this in `O(n^2)` time is to build an index for each query you want to do. Once you've got the machinery to query any value in constant time, your `O(n^2)` turns into `O(n)`, trivially. And you can build all of the indices in `O(n)` time, too.

Assuming each of your values has the same fields, it will look like this:

```
indices = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    for field in 'id', 'name', 'price', 'url':
        key = row[field]
        indices[field][key].add(i)
```

Now, to search for a specific value, it's just this:

```
def search(field, key):
    return (data[index] for index in indices[field][key])
```

To search for a group of values `or`ed together, just search them separately and `set.union` them together, like this:

```
def search_disj(factors):
    sets = (indices[field][key] for field, key in factors)
    return (data[index] for index in reduce(set.union, sets))
```

And to search for a group of disjunctions `and`ed together, do the same thing for each one, and then `set.intersection` all of the results together.

Depending on your data, it can be more efficient to just look up the first index, then linearly search the results for the other factors. You can optimize that further by reordering fields so you search the one with the smallest `len(indices[field])` first. (Or, in this case, the one with the smallest sum(len(indices[field]) for field in disj)`.)

If you can arbitrary nesting——conjunctions of disjunctions of conjunctions of … until you get down to single elements—you'll just have the functions call either other mutually recursively (with a base case for flat elements). You can even extend this to fully generally boolean search (although you'll also need a `not` operation—`universe - indices[field][key]`, where `universe = set(range(len(data)))`—for that).

---

If the data are very large, you may not be able to store all the indices in memory.

Or, even if you *can* stores all the indices in memory, cache and even page misses may make a hash table less than ideal, in which case you'll probably want to consider something based on a B-tree (e.g., `blist.sorteddict`) instead of a dict. This also gives you the advantage that you can search for ranges of values, order results, etc. The disadvantage is that all those `n` times become `n log n`, but if you need the functionality, or if you get a two-orders-of-magnitude locality benefit in exchange for a `log(n, base)` cost that turns out to be only 7, it can be worth it.

Or, alternatively, use some sort of disk-backed dict-like storage, like an `anydbm`.

---

However, really, what you're building is a relational database with only a single relation (table). In many cases, you'll be better off just using an off-the-shelf relational database—like `sqlite3`, which Python comes with built in. Then the code to build an index just looks like this:

```
db.execute('CREATE INDEX id_idx ON data (id)')
```

… and you can just do queries and they magically use the right indices in the best possible way:

```
curs = db.execute('SELECT * FROM data WHERE name = ? AND (price = ? OR url = ?)', 
                  filters)
```

Comment: Should `OR` and `AND` be swapped in that SQL statement?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yeah, you're right; I assumed he wanted disjunctions of conjunctions, because that's what people almost always want, but reading more carefully, he doesn't. The Python indices have the same problem. Thanks; I'll fix it.

Comment: The problem just got more complicated (several "and" conditions as well as several "or"s). I'll withdraw my answer. I don't have the time (it's time for bed!) to check if your answer works in those cases as well (it certainly looks more extensible than mine, especially the database-driven one)...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I think it's just a bunch of "and"s each of which is a bunch of "or"s, in which case it will still work. If you're more general (a bunch of "and"s each of which is a bunch of "or"s each of which is potentially a bunch of "and"s and so on), you just mutually-recursively call the disjunction function from the conjunction function and vice-versa (while singing the Schoolhouse Rock song). I can show that if the OP asks for it.

Comment: +1 "However, really, what you're building is a relational database".

Comment: I agree that using an SQL database would be a cleaner solution, unfortunately it doesn't fit well into my workflow. Still, a great answer, many thanks!

Comment: @thg435: Why doesn't it fit your workflow? Creating a `sqlite3` database (either in-memory or on-disk) is trivial.

Comment: @abarnert: My data is dynamic, that is, the function in question deals with different set of data on each call.

Comment: @thg435: You can create dynamic tables and indices by just doing string operations on the SQL, or using an ORM dynamically. _In general_ dynamic SQL statements are bad, because in general you have static tables and user-driven dynamic data, but there are some cases (maybe including this one) where they can be useful.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for your input. I'm self-accepting my answer as it works for me out of the box, but the sql approach is definitely worth considering in the future.